# PHP Echo pre-pend characters

Tags: php, echo

I have built a PHP echo statement like this:

```
<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['base'])); ?>
```

How do I omit the first 7 characters of the data that is returned?

Comment: take a look at [substr](http://www.php.net/substr)

Comment: settle down, school boys. both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/substr

```
<?php echo substr(rawurlencode($row['base']), 7); ?>
```

Comment: Oh man!  How could I miss that???  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$result = substr(rawurlencode($row['base']), 7);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: you have an extra close parenthesis in your syntax.